# Copy quality is good, but print quality is poor. How to fix it?

Tags: printing, printer

I can't achieve normal print quality on [Canon MF282DW](https://www.canon-europe.com/business/products/office-printers/multifunction/black-and-white/i-sensys-mf270-series/specifications/mf272dw.html) (monochrome laser).

I tried changing many settings, but it did not give a noticeable effect.

I also tried printing from different OS: Windows 11, Ubuntu, Android, iOS — almost the same result everywhere.

Changing the color mode from grayscale to monochrome doesn't change anything.

What could be causing this? And how can I fix this?

Print example:
[image: print example]

Copy example:
[image: copy example]

Printing example - PDF file printed from a browser (tried different browsers - Chrome, Edge, Firefox).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149966/discussion-on-question-by-abler98-copy-quality-is-good-but-print-quality-is-poo); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monochrome printers have inherent limitations. You would in the past, have used for example, a Fax machine and compensated for the printing limits. I am using a G4 tif here to show how Fax machines had similar issues.

- Lines should be black not grey and the same with text.
- Lines should be thick enough to not disappear since there are no subpixel settings in a facsimile just crude and cruder (faster).
- Fonts should be the onboard printer fonts,  (essential for mono printers like ZPL lable printers) never external vectors that have different stroke thicknesses.
- Basic graphics and diagrams need to consider what happens to colour tones such as grey.

[image]

How to fix is write the source with  a known monochrome printer in mind or use custom drivers that can compensate for monochrome source failings.

For a PDF the Acrobat Reader can try to remediate some issues. As an editor based app that knows PDF inside out, it can adjust the output to suit the printer and thus enhance the print. Here the same crude virtual Fax machine output, looks way better.

[image]

Unfortunately AFAIK, no other print system can enhance better, as say GhostScript is a very good alternative to Acrobat's Distiller and GS has "MonochromePrint (bool)" HOWEVER it is "For bjc600 only".

Other routes you can try to open the PDF in an image application and convert to mono then print however the lines and font strokes need to be thicker than defaults. So a rule of thumb is about 0.7 point or more 0.5 point is only good for highest grade printers.

[image]

If you pre-process the PDF to thicken and blacken the contents then an image printer does not need to compensate or get it wrong. Here same PDF is processed before opening by an image application that can print the image.

[image]

### Finally

Whatever you try in Monochrome with that source it is unlikely to be much improved beyond this image which you could send to printer at 100% scale. Either right click save as image or click on image then download.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I didn't expect the limitations to be so significant. In my case, I managed to increase the density to the maximum value in the printer settings and get a good result without additional processing